# How can I see what is the latest version of a package available in a specific repo if I have that package already installed/updated from another repo?

Tags: linux, yum

I am using CentOS 6 and I updated PHP using the Remi Repository. I would like to use *yum* in order to know what is the latest version available in the official CentOS repos. I tried issuing the following command:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=base,update info php
```

but I get

```
...
Version: [current installed version]
...
Repo: installed
From repo: remi
...
```

It seems that since the package is already installed I can't get this information. Is there any way to use *yum* to check that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the --showduplicates option, which is a somewhat confusing name but from yum's POV the available package is a duplicate of the installed one.

Also note that for recent versions of yum you can do:

```
yum repo-pkgs <repo> list foo
```

...which is somewhat easier.

Comment: Thanks. It is --showduplicates in my yum vresion though.

Comment: Yeh, sorry, it got fixed so that both work in newer versions but the one without the dash works "forever".